# How to set different shape color when hover state of image?

Tags: html, css

I have created three images in a column and I set `column-count: 3;` plus `border-width` for those three images. Now I need to know about the hover state.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h1 class="content-title"><span>Popular</span></h1>
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="popular">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/bq6aahcpn/Book_ll_4.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <a href="olymbic.html">
                <h2>Saina nehwal first match</h2>
                <p>fasdfjaksdksdfh skdfk</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="popular">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/bq6aahcpn/Book_ll_4.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <a href="#">
                <h2>Saina nehwal first match</h2>
                <p>fasdfjaksdksdfh skdfk</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="popular">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/bq6aahcpn/Book_ll_4.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <a href="#">
                <h2>Saina nehwal first match</h2>
                <p>fasdfjaksdksdfh skdfk</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I hover an image, it needs to look like this:

[image: hover-state].

And here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6g7v899q/

May I know, how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're images have a big white border around them,  crop that first.

Comment: is that important fact?

Comment: you will only be able to set the shadow up to the edge of the image unless you do extra programming and calculations to move the shadow over the image. even if you do that it would be hard to make it consistent cross browser.

Comment: here is my updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6g7v899q/1/

Comment: you still haven't cropped up to the image,look  [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6g7v899q/2/), you need to crop more.look at this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m761z871/) I just done

Answer (score 0):

something like this then ?

```css
img{margin:40px;border:25px solid white;}
img:hover{border-left:25px inset gray;border-right:25px outset gray;border-top:25px outset white;border-bottom:25px inset white;}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" width="200" height="200" />
```

Comment: I don't need like your answer.. I need when an hover, it shows like this, http://s14.postimg.org/juc8j51oh/Untitled_2.png .. I mean when hover state, it shows left rectangle and right rectangle shape..

Comment: can you please refer this site http://www.gatesnotes.com/ in reading post part?.. I need like this..

Comment: edited my answer, the picture you give actually has a faint border top and bottom aswell, if you want that then just change the border top and bottom color, don't forget to mark the answer